# Why do we have a validation bit for each entry in a page table?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, data-protection, page-tables

I was studying about paging memory management and, at a certain point, I found out that there's a bit associated with each entry of a page table to indicate if frame is a valid or invalid frame to be accessed by the process that is associated with this page table.

My question is: if a process has a dedicated page table, with entries that correspond to maps between its logical pages and the physical frames in memory, why would we need to add an external bit to indicate if a frame referenced by an entry in a process's own page table is accessible or not?

My own explanation is that a process may have, for some unknowns reasons for me, entries in its own page table that may not be used or become invalid for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The bits in a page table vary among systems. However, there are three states that a page table entry must accommodate:

1. The entry maps to a valid physical page frame (all ready to go).
2. The entry is valid but has no physical page is currently mapped (access triggers a page fault)
3. The entry is invalid (i.e. the page has not been mapped to the address space).

The page table must have bit settings (or some other means, e.g. null values) to represent these three states.

To illustrate State #3, linkers cause the first page not to be mapped when the program is loaded in order to trap references to null pointers.